# Selenium can't find elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, authentication, inspect

I am trying to login to a site through Selenium. All the sites on which I try to log in, I could do this less. After putting this part of the code shows me a Python 2.7 error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 350, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 499, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498537 (cb2f855cbc7b82e20387eaf9a43f6b99b6105061),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://car.com")
user= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onevideo_login_username"]')
user.send_keys("email")
```

Inspect:

```
<input type="text" id="onevideo_login_username" name="adaptv_email" data-i18n-placeholder="login.username" ng-model="models.login.email" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Username">
```

As I said before, I can login in all web sites I was trying, but this one is a headache!

Comment: check the url, doesn't seem that id with "onevideo_login_username" exists.

Comment: URL does not have any ID like this

Answer (score 0):

- Is the url correct?
- If you have id,then its better to use, 
  Try:

  ```
   user=driver.find_element_by_id('onevideo_login_username');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL, I guess your URL is not correct. First of all I did not find any element like this in URL, but as per html I suggest you locator to locate element

```
<input type="text" id="onevideo_login_username" name="adaptv_email" data-i18n-placeholder="login.username" ng-model="models.login.email" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Username">
```

Use ID

```
 user=driver.find_element_by_id('onevideo_login_username');
```

Use Name

```
user=driver.find_element_by_name('adaptv_email');
```

Use xpath

```
user= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="adaptv_email"]')
```

Comment: I did it and I don't receive any response, only errors about element not visible. With another library? request, urllib, mechanize??